# Use epoll to wait for a reader to connect to named pipes

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pipe, epoll

I'm writing an application where I'm creating a number of [named pipes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) (FIFO pipes), and I need to wait for a process to open one of these named pipes so I can send data to it.  However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to use `epoll` for this use case.

I tried opening the named pipes with the `O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK` flags (using `O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK` returns an `ENXIO` error), then use `epoll` to poll for the `EPOLLOUT` events.  However, for some reason the named pipes are immediately writable after I open them, so `epoll_wait` returns immediately, without waiting for readers to connect.

How do I use `epoll` to simultaneously wait for readers to connect to multiple named pipes?

Comment: If a FIFO is open for reading and writing, it is immediately available to write to, and possibly for readers to read from without blocking.

Comment: Can you remove the `O_NONBLOCK` flag after opening the file descriptor?  I suspect not.  You can only call `epoll()` for already open file descriptors, so the chances are that you can't use it to monitor when FIFOs are opened for reading.  Can you use multiple threads — one thread per pipe — to try opening the FIFOs, and letting the main thread know when there's a new thread for it to monitor.  Or something vaguely along those lines.  I've not thought through the implementation fully.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did consider a one-thread-per-pipe approach but since I can have a huge number of pipes, that risks exhausting OS threads, which is why I'm now considering using `epoll`.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a sensible way to wait for any of a number of unopened FIFOs to become openable because there's a reader or writer on the other end.  I'm not aware of one, but I don't know all the Linux system calls — there are a lot of them.